# How can I import a binary number with 256 places as a private key into my Litecoin wallet?

Tags: litecoin, e-wallet, import

I'm not a coder, so excuse the dummy terms:

I have 256 binary characters in 0's and 1's... This is a private key to my wallet... How the hell do I import this 0' and 1' into my Litecoin wallet.